# Match 0 to 60 in regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

What is the regular expression to match the numbers 0 through 60?  No negative numbers allowed and no decimals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:  `^([0-5]?[0-9]|60)$`

In C#:

```
int temp;
if (int.TryParse(str, out temp) && temp >= 0 && temp <= 60)
```

Comment: This matches only to 59 and it also matches negative values

Comment: I have heard that it is probably better not to use regular expressions here? Is this true?

Comment: This will match `60`.  To prevent negatives, you need to anchor the regex; otherwise, it will match the number after the `-`.  I edited it.

Comment: Correct; it's better to avoid regexes.  Which of my two options is more readable at first glance?

Comment: I tried on this website: http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ and it only matches the 6 of 60

Comment: That's because the first side of the `|` matched the `6`, and I forgot to group the `|` clause.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming Perl compatible regular expressions, and no leading zeroes

```
/([1-5]?[0-9]|60)/
```

Comment: I need the c# regular expression version?

Comment: @Xaisoft: they are Perl compatible.

Comment: @ScottSchluer that tag was added by BoltClock later (see the edit history)